# Different images in table View?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiimageview

I am quite new to the forum and id love some assistance. I have a table view and im able to add cells to it via different buttons on a seperate page. I want to have each button add a new cell but with a different image. So for example. Button 1 will add a cell and an image named `@"button1.png"` button two will add a cell with an image named `@"button2.png"` and so on. But im having trouble adding the image to the cell. I can do it in the `cellForRow`, but not in a button method. Could somebody please help me? I have tried this in the buttons:

***EDIT***
button used to add cell and image:

```
- (IBAction)outlet1:(id)sender {
[cart.cells addObject:@"1"];
[cart.cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"paddle1.png"]];
}
```

`cellForRow`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:   
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault     
reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
} 
//cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"paddle1.png"];
[myTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPath.row   
withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

cell.textLabel.text = [cells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way UITableView renders is that it asks for a cell for a row whenever it is about to render that row, generates the pixels that it needs, and then forgets about the cell. Since most of the structure of a cell doesn't change from row to row, there is the capability to re-use the same cell object for rendering multiple rows and just (eg) change label text or an imageView's image.

Hence, changing a cell after a row has been rendered doesn't change the appearance of the row. You need to tell the table to re-render that row:

```
[myTable reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathArray withRowAnimation:foo];
```

This will cause the OS to call the tableView's Data Source delegate `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` message, which then needs to create and/or modify a cell, which then gets rendered.

Cells aren't rows. Cells are objects used to *render* rows.

Comment: ok so when this method is called, it will reload the rows of the table and it will allow me to add new images to the tableview rows? Also what should i substitute foo for? Thanks a lot for the reply andrew! :)

Comment: Call the method with an indexPathArray that includes index paths to the rows that you want to change. As for 'foo', pick a row animation that you want, eg UITableViewRowAnimationNone if you just want it to redraw immediately. Check the documentation on this message for more information.

Comment: ok so i put this in the cellForRow with this code: `[myTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPath.row withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];` and it still doesnt allow the picture to be added. And if i add more than 1 cell and then try to go to the tableView page, the app crashes. Here could you please read over my code in my question ill fix it and show what i have now. Thanks a lot for all of the help!!

Comment: that first parameter is an array - you need `[myTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];` That could be causing your crash. If you want multiple rows, then use a different array initializer message.

Comment: hey andrew, i appreciate the help, but this isnt what im looking for at all i think. Its making my table view do a bunch of weird things. Have you seen the amazon app for the iphone/ipad? I want the same thing as when you add something to the cart to purchase it. I want a cell to appear with the products image. Could you help me with this please? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem, you want a cart object to display its picture in a table cell.  If this is true, then why don't you add an UIImage view to the cart object.  At an appropriate time (somewhere where the object is select by the user) store the image of the item to your UIImage view of the object.  Then when you go to set the cart object into your table, you have then objects name (presumably) and it's image in your object and you can then easily set the cell's image = to your objects image.  Don't try to have the logic of which image to display inside the "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method.  Store the image and all attributes with your object and use the objectAtIndex to point to your complete object and set your cell based on your objects attributes.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the reply!! And the cart object is just a copy of a class. And as for adding the image at an appropriate time, wouldnt my code work above? I have the user press a button and then it adds it then when it adds the cell/row? You keep saying cart object. What do you mean by this? What do you think cart is? because , im not sure how to word this, but cart is just reffering to a different class

Comment: Did you get this figured out?

Comment: Yeah i sure did, i just added the images to an array like the text for the cell. And it worked perfect! Thanks for the help!